# Ошибка при подключении “ORA-12505: TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor”

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g

Установила Oracle11g, настроила подключение в идее - все ок.
Но в итоге выдает такую ошибку:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:458)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:546)
.....
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что такое myDB? Где вы его установили при установке БД?

Answer (score 2):

В поле *Service* надо ввести имя сервиса БД, а не имя БД.
По умолчанию имя сервиса состоит из параметров:

- `DB_NAME` - имя БД, которое было задано при установке, например, `myDB`
- `DOMAIN_NAME` - по умолчанию домен сервера БД, например, `mydomain.ru`

То есть надо ввести: `Service: [myDB.mydomain.ru   ]`

Узнать, какие сервисы зарегистрированы в прослушивателе можно командой:

```
$ lsnrctl status
```